# C memory allocation sequence for struct data

Tags: c, malloc

I am reading a C scripts written by someone else. I don't understand this memory allocation part.

```
lda_suffstats* ss = malloc(sizeof(lda_suffstats));
ss->class_total = malloc(sizeof(double)*num_topics);
ss->class_word = malloc(sizeof(double*)*num_topics);
```

where lda_suffstats is a self-defined structure,

```
typedef struct
{
double** class_word;
double* class_total;
double alpha_suffstats;
int num_docs;
} lda_suffstats;
```

My question is regarding the first line of memory allocation. What is the size of lda_suffstats? Shouldn't the memory for each of its component be allocated before itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can know how big `lda_suffstats` will be before you actually have one, just like you know how big of a bag you need to have with you in order to fit two cartons of milk and a dozen eggs. A size of `lda_suffstats` is a sum of sizes of `double**`, `double*`, `double` and `int`, no more, no less. They are not independent components, they'll all use the memory of the `lda_suffstats`. Now, the first two are pointers, which means the associated value is not right there but only pointed to, and allocating the target of the pointers is what the other two `malloc` lines are about.

Answer (score 1):

`lda_suffstats` has four fields with the types of `double**`, `double*`, `double`, and `int`. The size of each of these is known at compile time. The sum of their sizes gives the size of `lda_suffstats`. The amount of memory allocated to the pointers does not change this because that memory is allocated outside of the `struct`.